# How to subtract timedelta from Timestamp, support negative returns

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe containing two columns : `timestamp` and `arrival_time`,  of `Timestamp` and `timedelta` types:

```
        timestamp   arrival_time
0   2015-01-28 05:30:47 0 days 05:30:33.000000000
1   2015-01-28 05:31:50 0 days 05:31:00.000000000
2   2015-01-28 05:32:21 0 days 05:31:43.000000000
3   2015-01-28 05:32:53 0 days 05:31:43.000000000
4   2015-01-28 05:33:57 0 days 05:32:58.000000000
5   2015-01-28 05:34:28 0 days 05:33:39.000000000
6   2015-01-28 05:35:00 0 days 05:34:23.000000000
7   2015-01-28 05:35:31 0 days 05:34:23.000000000
8   2015-01-28 05:36:02 0 days 05:36:00.000000000
9   2015-01-28 05:36:34 0 days 05:36:00.000000000
10  2015-01-28 05:37:07 0 days 05:36:38.000000000
11  2015-01-28 05:37:38 0 days 05:36:38.000000000
12  2015-01-28 05:38:41 0 days 05:39:00.000000000
13  2015-01-28 05:39:13 0 days 05:39:00.000000000
14  2015-01-28 05:39:44 0 days 05:40:12.000000000
```

I want to find the mean difference of the two. However, simple subtraction will cause a problem for rows like row `12`: It will return, correctly, `23:59:41`. But I want it to return a negative value (i.e. `-00:00:19`) or sth like that.

Should I just completely change their types from dates to integers or is there a better solution?

**EDIT:** it acts weird again when the difference is more than a day:

```
3694    2015-01-29 01:10:27 1 days 01:11:27
```

Here it now returns

```
3694   -2 days +23:59:00
```

where it should return `-00:01:00`

Comment: Does this mean that for these two sets of data you want the same result? 2015-01-29 01:10:27 1 days 01:11:27 AND 2015-01-29 01:10:27 2 days 01:11:27?  These should both equal -00:01:00?  I'm struggling with what the timedelta is a time difference between?  How are these being created?

Comment: Yes, I want them to be the same. Data actually comes from this https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference?hl=en#stop_timestxt

Comment: @RobertRodkey but it's fine, I'll correct it wth some dirty hacks. Your answer solved my first problem, so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED per comments**
If I'm reading this right, you basically want to know what the time difference is relative to start of the day in each timestamp.  I set up a test case here and provided another snippet of code.  Let me know if we're on the same page now.

```
In [123]: test_df
Out[123]:
            timestamp  arrival_time
0 2015-01-28 05:30:47      05:31:34

In [124]: test_df.dtypes
Out[124]:
timestamp        datetime64[ns]
arrival_time    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object

In [125]: test_df['result'] = (test_df['timestamp'] - test_df['arrival_time']) - test_df['timestamp'].apply(pd.Timestamp.date).apply(pd.Timestamp)

In [126]: test_df
Out[126]:
            timestamp  arrival_time    result
0 2015-01-28 05:30:47      05:31:34 -00:00:47
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_seconds'. but Even before that, the result of previous substractions is, for first row for example, -1 days +18:29:27.

Comment: Missed the dataframe part!  Let me edit this into that framework.

Comment: It worked for the most part, see edit please. And about the question, it's that timestamp start at 27th and continues till 30th, and arrival_time starts from zero to 72 hrs for example